# 'Abort' reading of cassandra results

Tags: node.js, cassandra, datastax-enterprise

I have a cql that I need to execute and stream the results using the [node.js driver](https://github.com/datastax/nodejs-driver#row-streaming-and-pipes). However, if a certain condition is met, I need to abort the streaming.

Something like this:

```
                client.eachRow(cql, [], {
                    autoPage: true
                }, function(n, row) {
                    if(applySomeFilterLogic(row) === 'some val') {
                        //abort streaming
                    } else {
                        rows.push(row);
                    }
                }, function(err, result) {
                    logger.error("server responded with error : %s", err);
                });
```

Data cannot be pre-processed with the filtering logic and persisted in cassandra. It needs to computed at runtime, based on a number of criteria that are not known when the data is persisted.

Is there a way of gracefully achieving this with node.js driver or cassandra in general?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [manual paging](http://datastax.github.io/nodejs-driver/features/paging/#manual-paging) instead:

```
const options = { prepare : true };
client.eachRow(query, parameters, options, function (n, row) { 
     // Invoked per each row in all the pages
  }, function (err, result) {
     // Called once the page has been fully retrieved.
     if (yourCondition && result.nextPage) {
       // Retrieve the following pages based on your condition:
       // the same row handler from above will be used
       result.nextPage();
     }
  }
);
```

You can read more information on the driver documentation: http://datastax.github.io/nodejs-driver/features/paging/

Comment: This works fine to pure CQL queries. However in case of CQL with a `solr_query` in the where clause the pagination is not happening. Is this a known limitation of the node.js driver/DSE Cassandra?